# Странная ситуация с java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out

Tags: java, сокет, многопоточность, swing

Здравствуйте.
Не пойму одного момента.
Следующий код в простом приложении отрабатывается "на отлично":

```
    package javaapplication12;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.Date;

    /**
     *
     * @author AKhusnutdinov
     */
    public class JavaApplication12 {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Date startDate = new Date();
            String hostname = "ihtik.lib.ru";
            int port = 80;

            Socket socket = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), 30000);
                String writer = "GET /2011.06.03_prislan.ihtiku/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        + "Host: " + hostname + "\r\n"
                        + "Accept: */*\r\n"
                        + "User-Agent: Java\r\n"
                        + "\r\n";
                socket.getOutputStream().write(writer.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                socket.getOutputStream().flush();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    //                if (line.isEmpty()) {
    //                    break; // Stop when headers are completed. We're not interested in all the HTML.
    //                }
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
                    }
                }

                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
                    }
                }
            }

            Date endDate = new Date();
            System.out.println(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
        }
    }
```

Но в GUI приложении, которое было создано в NetBeans (Настольное приложение Java, Swing) аналогичный код не отрабатывает, а именно выдаёт ошибку :

```
run:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:125)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:459)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at desktopapplication1.DesktopApplication1View.<init>(DesktopApplication1View.java:46)
    at desktopapplication1.DesktopApplication1.startup(DesktopApplication1.java:19)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
ПОСТРОЕНИЕ УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНО (общее время: 39 секунд)
```

Вырезка кода GUI аппликэйшена:

```
package desktopapplication1;

import org.jdesktop.application.Action;
import org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;
import org.jdesktop.application.TaskMonitor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * The application's main frame.
 */
public class DesktopApplication1View extends FrameView {

    public DesktopApplication1View(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        super(app);

        initComponents();

        Date startDate = new Date();
        String hostname = "ihtik.lib.ru";
        int portt = 80;

        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, portt), 30000);
            String writer = "GET /2011.06.03_prislan.ihtiku/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                    + "Host: " + hostname + "\r\n"
                    + "Accept: */*\r\n"
                    + "User-Agent: Java\r\n"
                    + "\r\n";
            socket.getOutputStream().write(writer.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            socket.getOutputStream().flush();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
//                if (line.isEmpty()) {
//                    break; // Stop when headers are completed. We're not interested in all the HTML.
//                }
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // status bar initialization - message timeout, idle icon and busy animation, etc
        ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
        int messageTimeout = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.messageTimeout");
        messageTimer = new Timer(messageTimeout, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                statusMessageLabel.setText("");
            }
        });
*******************************************************
```

Почему выдаётся ошибка?

Comment: вы, наверно, это и так проверили, но спрошу на всякий случай - первый код точно не выдает исключений? Они у вас там просто пропускаются по-тихому.

Comment: Проверял :).
Данные через  System.out.println(line); выводятся в первом примере...

Answer (score 3):

1. Убираем нахер вашу хитрую проксю, и тестируем проблемный GUI код - чтобы коннектился к серверу напрямую. Это надо было сделать в первую очередь!
2. Если проблема исчезает (что вряд ли), это повод подумать.
3. Если проблема остается, возвращаемся к аспектам многопоточности. Как вы используете SwingWorker? Приведите реализацию этого класса, а также код, который его использует. Используете ли вы где-либо метод SwingWorker.get? Как создаете "воркера" и запускаете его на выполнение?
4. При запуске программы запрошенные 30 секунд на таймаут выдерживаются? Или исключение вываливается сразу?

В зависимости от полученных результатов будем думать дальше.

Answer (score 1):

[Аналогичный вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577719/java-sockets-bufferedreader-and-readline-hang).
`readLine()` возвращает `null`, если подошли к концу потока. Однако тут сервер не закрывает соединение после окончания передачи данных, а ожидает дальнейших запросов. У вас есть несколько вариантов:

- указать протокол HTTP/1.0;
- указать заголовок Connection: close;
- считать Content-Length из ответа сервера и ожидать нужное количество данных.

На счет работы первого случая - вывод-то есть, но завершается ли работа приложения сразу после вывода?

Comment: Дело в том, что код в примерах почти что одинаковый и данные во втором примере вообще не приходят - сокет в таймаут падает. Это не решение. Вопрос именно в том, что во втором примере в GUI аппликухе таймаут почему-то выбивает.

Comment: Вопрос еще и в том, почему у меня он не выбивает :)

Comment: Я за проксёй хитрой сижу...
Прокся пропускает коннекты первого кода, но не пропускает коннекты второго кода. Идеи?

Comment: хм... у Socket есть конструктор, который принимает Proxy - его попробовать? А еще - я не специалист в Swing, но у меня складывается впечатление, что такие вот блокирующие I/O вызовы лучше делать в отдельном потоке.

Comment: тааааак. а можно подробнее с этого момента? Пробовал и SwingWorker и  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doWorkRunnable); - не помогло. Так же таймаут...

Comment: Ну, может, попробовать выполнить загрузку в отдельном потоке? Честно говоря, сомневаюсь, что выполнение долгих операций в потоке, который работает с GUI-компонентами, повлияет на что-нибудь кроме чувствительности приложения к действиям пользователя, но мало ли.

Comment: SwingWorker не помог...  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doWorkRunnable); тоже не помогло... Чую, что GUI блочит коннекты...